# AWS Service Catalog: ProvisioningArtifact must not be DEPRECATED

Tags: amazon-web-services, logic, cloud, aws-cloudformation

I have this case where the CloudFormation stack failed to be updated because the provisioned artifact became a deprecated version.

From a Design Rule, I'm deprecating old versions and only activating the latest version of the AWS Service Catalog product. This was designed to control and manage SC usage for users.

This error was shown after the CloudFormation rollback:

> **Unable to update provisioned product because: ProvisioningArtifact must not be DEPRECATED**

do you suggest how to overcome this issue? any design tips to control the case?